# API testing using karate framework Data driven testing

Tags: api, testing, automated-tests, karate, data-driven-tests

Currently our project is using Karate Framework for API test automation. So we have a scenario where we need to use the concept of Data driven testing i.e we need to test automate an API where we send the input as Excel file. Now as we get the JSON response on running the API, we need to match the excel sheet input with output JSON response we get.

For example:
Please find the attached screenshots, where I've taken an public API to automate and passed Excel sheet as input parameter where in which for each iteration, API takes input from each row at one 1shot.Now we get an output in the form of JSON response. So, we need to match the output JSON response with our input excel sheet...

In more detail, if you take our current project working scenario, we get the excel sheet from commerce team which is considered as master data, API is developed & integrated by another team, we(QA team) need to validate the JSON response we get on hitting the API URL.
We need to pass the Excel sheet as input(Each iteration will take 1 row as input) to the API URL, hit the API, fetch the API response and compare with input excel sheet through which we can identify the scenarios where the mismatching of the data is taken place.

Thanks in advance. Please reply back to my query

[Feature file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef4vh.png)
[Input excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q192W.png)

Comment: if the linked answer does not answer your question, please assume that what you want is not supported by karate